# Can lambda outside of VPC access aurora rds using rds proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

With the launch of RDS-Proxy, is it possible for a non-vpc lambda accessing a private aurora rds using rds-proxy IAM authentication?

Have anyone tried?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. To access any service inside the VPC, Lambda should be linked to that VPC.
Please refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html).